# Prevent django admin from running SELECT COUNT(*) on the list form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Every time I use Admin to list the entries of a model, the Admin count the rows in the table. Worse yet, it seems to be doing so even when you are filtering your query.

For instance if I want to show only the models whose id is 123, 456, 789 I can do:

```
/admin/myapp/mymodel/?id__in=123,456,789
```

But the queries ran (among others) are:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myapp_mymodel` WHERE `myapp_mymodel`.`id` IN (123, 456, 789) # okay
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myapp_mymodel` # why???
```

Which is killing mysql+innodb. It seems that the problem is partially acknowledged [in this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8408), but my issue seems more specific since it counts all the rows even if it is not supposed to.

Is there a way to disable that global rows count?

Note: I am using django 1.2.7.

Comment: When you filter it displays e.g. "21 results (3011 total)", so the `count(*)` is required to display the total. To turn that off, I think you're going to have to do a lot of hacking the django admin app.

Comment: Now I see, thanks. I guess we will have to wait for that ticket to go through, then.

Comment: `Note: I am using django 1.2.7.` - consider upgrading.

Comment: Yeah I will, but this is an old project.

Comment: Btw, I have already found a solution but since I have less than 100 reputation I'll have to wait to post it. :p

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay, I think I found a solution. As Peter suggested, the best approach is to work on the `count` property and it can be done by overriding it with custom query set (as seen in  [this post](http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2011/07/django_admin_with_large_tables/)) that specialises the count with an approximate equivalent:

```
from django.db import connections, models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class ApproxCountQuerySet(QuerySet):
    """Counting all rows is very expensive on large Innodb tables. This
    is a replacement for QuerySet that returns an approximation if count()
    is called with no additional constraints. In all other cases it should
    behave exactly as QuerySet.

    Only works with MySQL. Behaves normally for all other engines.
    """

    def count(self):
        # Code from django/db/models/query.py

        if self._result_cache is not None and not self._iter:
            return len(self._result_cache)

        is_mysql = 'mysql' in connections[self.db].client.executable_name.lower()

        query = self.query
        if (is_mysql and not query.where and
                query.high_mark is None and
                query.low_mark == 0 and
                not query.select and
                not query.group_by and
                not query.having and
                not query.distinct):
            # If query has no constraints, we would be simply doing
            # "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo". Monkey patch so the we
            # get an approximation instead.
            cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
            cursor.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE %s",
                    (self.model._meta.db_table,))
            return cursor.fetchall()[0][4]
        else:
            return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
```

Then in the admin:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs._clone(klass=ApproxCountQuerySet)
```

The approximate function could mess things up on page number 100000, but it is good enough for my case.

Comment: Thanks. With a little tweaking, this also worked for me in PostgreSQL, although I had to use the query `SELECT reltuples::int FROM pg_class WHERE oid = '%s'::regclass;`

Comment: @LS55321 Any idea how we can use ApproxCountQuerySet?

Comment: I think for modern Django you would use `def get_queryset` (as described by Paweł Krzyżaniak in another answer), and replace `return qs._clone(klass=ApproxCountQuerySet)` with `return qs._chain(__class__= ApproxCountQuerySet)`.

Comment: @JackCushman I'm on django 4 and neither is working for me, with your suggestion I get:  _chain() got an unexpected keyword argument '__class__'

Comment: any solution for modern django versions?

Answer (score 32):

Django 1.8 lets you disable this by setting `show_full_result_count = False`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.show_full_result_count

Comment: This is only on a filtered queryset. If you're hitting the admin without filters, it will still generate use SELECT COUNT(*)...

Comment: In addition to setting show_full_result_count=False, you also need to override the default paginator. See [e4c5's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208299/107106) for an example.

Answer (score 12):

I found Nova's answer very helpful, but i use postgres. I modified it slightly to work for postgres with some slight alterations to handle table namespaces, and slightly different "detect postgres" logic.

Here's the pg version.

```
class ApproxCountPgQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
  """approximate unconstrained count(*) with reltuples from pg_class"""

  def count(self):
      if self._result_cache is not None and not self._iter:
          return len(self._result_cache)

      if hasattr(connections[self.db].client.connection, 'pg_version'):
          query = self.query
          if (not query.where and query.high_mark is None and query.low_mark == 0 and
              not query.select and not query.group_by and not query.having and not query.distinct):
              # If query has no constraints, we would be simply doing
              # "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo". Monkey patch so the we get an approximation instead.
              parts = [p.strip('"') for p in self.model._meta.db_table.split('.')]
              cursor = connections[self.db].cursor()
              if len(parts) == 1:
                  cursor.execute("select reltuples::bigint FROM pg_class WHERE relname = %s", parts)
              else:
                  cursor.execute("select reltuples::bigint FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n on (c.relnamespace = n.oid) WHERE n.nspname = %s AND c.relname = %s", parts)
          return cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
      return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
```

Comment: return cursor should be indented

Answer (score 6):

The Nova's solution (ApproxCountQuerySet) works great, however in newer versions of Django queryset method got replaced with get_queryset, so it now should be:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs._clone(klass=ApproxCountQuerySet)
```

Comment: I get an error with klass `_clone() got an unexpected keyword argument 'klass'`

Answer (score 4):

If this is a serious problem you may have to take Drastic Actions™.

Looking at the code for a 1.3.1 install, I see that the admin code is using the paginator returned by `get_paginator()`. The default paginator class appears to be in `django/core/paginator.py`. That class has a private value called `_count` which is set in `Paginator._get_count()` (line 120 in my copy). This in turn is used to set a *property* of the Paginator class called `count`. I think that `_get_count()` is your target. Now the stage is set.

You have a couple of options:

1. Directly modify the source. I do *not* recommend this, but since you seem to be stuck at 1.2.7 you may find that it is the most expedient. *Remember to document this change!* Future maintainers (including possibly yourself) will thank you for the heads up.
2. Monkeypatch the class. This is better than direct modification because a) if you don't like the change you just comment out the monkeypatch, and b) it is more likely to work with future versions of Django. I have a monkeypatch going back over 4 years because they still have not fixed a bug in the template variable `_resolve_lookup()` code that doesn't recognize callables at the top level of evaluation, only at lower levels. Although the patch (which wraps the method of a class) was written against 0.97-pre, it still works at 1.3.1.

I did not spend the time to figure out exactly what changes you would have to make for your problem, but it might be along the lines of adding a `_approx_count` member to appropriate classes `class META` and then testing to see if that attr exists. If it does and is `None` then you do the `sql.count()` and set it. You might also need to reset it if you are on (or near) the last page of the list. Contact me if you need a little more help on this; my email is in my profile.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to [change the default paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.paginator) used by the admin class. Here's one that caches the result for a short period of time: https://gist.github.com/e4c5/6852723

Answer (score 4):

I managed to create a custom paginator that shows the current page numbe, a next button and a show full count link. It allows for the use of the original paginator if needed.

[image]

The trick used is to take `per_page + 1` elements from db in order to see if we have more elements and then provide a fake count.

Let's say that we want the the third page and the page has 25 elements => We want `object_list[50:75]`. When calling `Paginator.count` the queryset will be evaluated for `object_list[50:76]`(note that we take **75+1** elements) and then return either the count as 76 if we got 25+1 elements from db or 50 + the number of elements received if we didn't received 26 elements.

---

TL;DR:
I've created a mixin for the `ModelAdmin`:

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class FastCountPaginator(Paginator):
    """A faster paginator implementation than the Paginator. Paginator is slow
    mainly because QuerySet.count() is expensive on large queries.

    The idea is to use the requested page to generate a 'fake' count. In
    order to see if the page is the final one  it queries n+1 elements
    from db then reports the count as page_number * per_page + received_elements.
    """

    use_fast_pagination = True

    def __init__(self, page_number, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page_number = page_number
        super(FastCountPaginator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        # Populate the object list when count is called. As this is a cached property,
        # it will be called only once per instance
        return self.populate_object_list()

    def page(self, page_number):
        """Return a Page object for the given 1-based page number."""
        page_number = self.validate_number(page_number)
        return self._get_page(self.object_list, page_number, self)

    def populate_object_list(self):
        # converts queryset object_list to a list and return the number of elements until there
        # the trick is to get per_page elements + 1 in order to see if the next page exists.
        bottom = self.page_number * self.per_page
        # get one more object than needed to see if we should show next page
        top = bottom + self.per_page + 1
        object_list = list(self.object_list[bottom:top])
        # not the last page
        if len(object_list) == self.per_page + 1:
            object_list = object_list[:-1]
        else:
            top = bottom + len(object_list)
        self.object_list = object_list
        return top


class ModelAdminFastPaginationMixin:
    show_full_result_count = False  # prevents root_queryset.count() call

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        # strip count_all query parameter from the request before it is processed
        # this allows all links to be generated like this parameter was not present and without raising errors
        request.GET = request.GET.copy()
        request.GET.paginator_count_all = request.GET.pop('count_all', False)

        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    def get_paginator(self, request, queryset, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True):
        # use the normal paginator if we want to count all the ads
        if hasattr(request.GET, 'paginator_count_all') and request.GET.paginator_count_all:
            return Paginator(queryset, per_page, orphans, allow_empty_first_page)
        page = self._validate_page_number(request.GET.get('p', '0'))
        return FastCountPaginator(page, queryset, per_page, orphans, allow_empty_first_page)

    def _validate_page_number(self, number):
        # taken from Paginator.validate_number and adjusted
        try:
            if isinstance(number, float) and not number.is_integer():
                raise ValueError
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return 0
        if number < 1:
            number = 0
        return number
```

The `pagination.html` template:

```
{% if cl and cl.paginator and cl.paginator.use_fast_pagination %}
    {# Fast paginator with only next button and show the total number of results#}
    {% load admin_list %}
    {% load i18n %}
    {% load admin_templatetags %}
    <p class="paginator">
        {% if pagination_required %}
            {% for i in page_range %}
                {% if forloop.last %}
                    {% fast_paginator_number cl i 'Next' %}
                {% else %}
                    {% fast_paginator_number cl i %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% show_count_all_link cl "showall" %}
    </p>
{% else %}
    {#  use the default pagination template if we are not using the FastPaginator  #}
    {% include "admin/pagination.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

and templatetags used:

```py
from django import template
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import PAGE_VAR
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

DOT = '.'


@register.simple_tag
def fast_paginator_number(cl, i, text_display=None):
    """Generate an individual page index link in a paginated list.

    Allows to change the link text by setting text_display
    """
    if i == DOT:
        return '… '
    elif i == cl.page_num:
        return format_html('<span class="this-page">{}</span> ', i + 1)
    else:
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}"{}>{}</a> ',
            cl.get_query_string({PAGE_VAR: i}),
            mark_safe(' class="end"' if i == cl.paginator.num_pages - 1 else ''),
            text_display if text_display else i + 1,
        )


@register.simple_tag
def show_count_all_link(cl, css_class='', text_display='Show the total number of results'):
    """Generate a button that toggles between FastPaginator and the normal
    Paginator."""
    return format_html(
        '<a href="{}"{}>{}</a> ',
        cl.get_query_string({PAGE_VAR: cl.page_num, 'count_all': True}),
        mark_safe(f' class="{css_class}"' if css_class else ''),
        text_display,
    )
```

You can use it this way:

```py
class MyVeryLargeModelAdmin(ModelAdminFastPaginationMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
# ...
```

---

Or an even simpler version that does not show the *Next* button and *Show the total number of results* :

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class FastCountPaginator(Paginator):
    """A faster paginator implementation than the Paginator. Paginator is slow
    mainly because QuerySet.count() is expensive on large queries.

    The idea is to use the requested page to generate a 'fake' count. In
    order to see if the page is the final one  it queries n+1 elements
    from db then reports the count as page_number * per_page + received_elements.
    """

    use_fast_pagination = True

    def __init__(self, page_number, *args, **kwargs):
        self.page_number = page_number
        super(FastCountPaginator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        # Populate the object list when count is called. As this is a cached property,
        # it will be called only once per instance
        return self.populate_object_list()

    def page(self, page_number):
        """Return a Page object for the given 1-based page number."""
        page_number = self.validate_number(page_number)
        return self._get_page(self.object_list, page_number, self)

    def populate_object_list(self):
        # converts queryset object_list to a list and return the number of elements until there
        # the trick is to get per_page elements + 1 in order to see if the next page exists.
        bottom = self.page_number * self.per_page
        # get one more object than needed to see if we should show next page
        top = bottom + self.per_page + 1
        object_list = list(self.object_list[bottom:top])
        # not the last page
        if len(object_list) == self.per_page + 1:
            object_list = object_list[:-1]
        else:
            top = bottom + len(object_list)
        self.object_list = object_list
        return top


class ModelAdminFastPaginationMixin:
    show_full_result_count = False  # prevents root_queryset.count() call

    def get_paginator(self, request, queryset, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True):
        page = self._validate_page_number(request.GET.get('p', '0'))
        return FastCountPaginator(page, queryset, per_page, orphans, allow_empty_first_page)

    def _validate_page_number(self, number):
        # taken from Paginator.validate_number and adjusted
        try:
            if isinstance(number, float) and not number.is_integer():
                raise ValueError
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return 0
        if number < 1:
            number = 0
        return number
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot and am trying to adapt it for my use case. Could you clarify, why you want that custom `._validate_page_number(...)` method in your Admin Mixin? Isn't this handled by/in the Paginator class? I understand the need to retrieve the page number from the request object, but why the additional validation?

Comment: @JohnGalt I could not use the build in `validate_number` from `Paginator` because it uses `self.num_pages` property that  makes a `Count(*)` query

Comment: But your Mixin calls the`._validate_page_number(...)` Method **only if** the Admin determines to use the `FastCountPaginator` anyway. And the `.num_pages` property calls the `.count` property which you overrode in your custom paginator to **not** do the `COUNT(*)` query. Please correct me, if I am wrong/missing something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 

The problem lies in the fact that `Paginator.count()` is called before the pagination has the number of pages. See [ChangeList sourcecode](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L225): first the paginator is instantiated *without* the page number. In the next line `Paginator.count` is called. 

In my custom implementation I need to know the page number in order to return the fake count. To do this I pass the page number in constructor then use it to `populate_object_list` when `count` is called.

This could be done better...

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer that made my life easier. However, I did find an issue with it with the page number specified in the url being decremented from the real page number.
Basically if you don't specify a page number with `?p=xx` in the URL you get the first page but if you choose `?p=1` you actually get the second page...

Comment: @Insomniak, you can how you read the page query parameter to start from 1: `request.GET.get('p', '1')-1`. This will make `?p=1` be the first page served

Comment: Indeed that's what I ended up doing, with : 
`page = self._validate_page_number(int(request.GET.get('p', '1'))-1)` and this is working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TimescaleDB then the following works well:

```py
class HyperTablePaginator(Paginator):
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        query = self.object_list.query
        if query.where:
            return super().count

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM approximate_row_count(%s);", [query.model._meta.db_table])
            return int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```