# slow count(*) on innoDB

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I have a table `message_message` with 3000000 records.

when I make a count(*) query, It's very slow...:

mysql>  `select count(*) from message_message`;

+----------+

| count(*) |

+----------+

|  2819416 |

+----------+

1 row in set (2 min 35.35 sec)

explain it:
mysql> `explain select count(*) from message_message`;

| id | select_type| table  | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  |Extra |

|  1 | SIMPLE | message_message | index | NULL  | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 2939870 | Using index |

1 row in set (0.02 sec)

what happen?

Comment: Do you need an exact number, or will an estimate do?

Comment: Django admin need a exact number for pagination :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433173/prevent-django-admin-from-running-select-count-on-the-list-form 
sloved！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [This Post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/) in InnoDB you need to do a full table scan, where as in MyISAM  its a index read.

If you use a `where` clause though it changes the execution pattern to use indexes, so in general InnoDB will be slower than MyISAM on full unrestricted counts, where as the performance matches up on restricted counts.

Comment: This is incorrect; in MyISAM it reads a single stored value; in innodb it does a full index read (not a full table scan) (which is exactly what the linked post says)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the amount of records, it's better to query the whole table and use the num_rows property of the result set. `Count(...)` is usually used when you want to have aggregate queries (in combination with `GROUP BY`).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.