# mysql 2.5M rows slow count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

Having a simple mysql table with `id` (primary key) and `hash` (index). Some other columns (varchar / int) but no queries on them needed.

My total table size is around 350MB with 2.5M rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

Is taking about 0.5 - 1s. My innodb buffer is set at 1GB. I've also tried variations (without improvements) like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table LIMIT 1;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id > 0 LIMIT 1;
```

A single

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'x' LIMIT 1;
```

would return within 1 ms (localhost mysql). Any tips on improving the slow count (0.5 - 1s) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have found for me, that MyISAM tables make these operations faster. But not all tables and architectures can be MyISAM. Check your schema, maybe you can switch this table to MyISAM.

Also use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`

And another technique for you. Create trigger and save count in separated place. Create `counter_table` and folowing trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_counter AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE counter_table
    SET counter = counter + 1
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a bried explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505732/slow-count-on-innodb). In short, innodb has to make a full table scan in order to count all rows (without a where clause, which would utilize an index).
See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505732/slow-count-on-innodb).

BTW, I can't see any point in using `LIMIT 1` in your query. Since there is no `group by` clause, it will always return one record.

Comment: But as I'm only using the primary key, shouldn't it use the memory as it won't need a key? I've even tested on 1GB inno db buffer (4gb ram machine).

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is your friend. Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on your statements and verify that an index is used. If not, you can force usage by `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table USE INDEX (PRIMARY)`